# PIP Install ERROR: Cannot set --home and --prefix together

Tags: python, pip

I am not using --home or --prefix in my pip install command but this error doesn't allow a git repo to be installed.

````
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [8 lines of output]
      Collecting setuptools>=40.8.0
        Using cached setuptools-62.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (1.2 MB)
      Collecting wheel
        Using cached wheel-0.37.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
      Installing collected packages: wheel, setuptools
      ERROR: Cannot set --home and --prefix together
      WARNING: You are using pip version 22.0.4; however, version 22.1 is available.
      You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\Rizwan computers\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.```
````

Comment: What command *are* you running that results in this error?

Comment: I am running: `python -m pip install git+https://github.com/mccoderpy/discord.py-message-components.git@developer`. I am able to run this command on my hosting server. But on my pc I don't know what I did to pip, it fails

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue on Windows 10 with Python 3.7.3 and pip 21.3.1. The issue was resolved when I removed the `target` from `pip\pip.ini`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me! 
 If anyone need to know if you have a pip.ini configured, you can run the command `pip config debug`

Answer (score 1):

Derived my solution from @PApostol and @Titou

```
unset PIP_TARGET
```

That's all I had to do to make the error go away. Got to know about the env var from `pip config debug`

Answer (score 1):

it could be solved by this way:
PIP_TARGET= pip install numpy

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a VS Code Dev container using Poetry to install our dependencies. Seems to be something in `pip` itself as reported in [this issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8438).

I ended up removing all the lines of our `.devcontainer/Dockerfile` that had `PIP_TARGET` in them. Our setup didn't really need them so that change worked just fine.

Comment: Yeah it was issue with pip config list, I removed all configs and everything is working fine now.