# Failed to install dependency in My PC development environment

Tags: installation, pip, apache-superset

When I run the command in the project root directory, the following error message is displayed

```
pip install -r requirements/development.txt
```

```
 Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [12 lines of output]
      Looking in indexes: http://mirrors.aliyun.com/pypi/simple/
      Collecting setuptools
        Downloading http://mirrors.aliyun.com/pypi/packages/c7/42/be1c7bbdd83e1bfb160c94b9cafd8e25efc7400346cf7ccdbdb452c467fa/setuptools-68.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (804 kB)
           -------------------------------------- 804.0/804.0 kB 1.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
      Collecting wheel
        Downloading http://mirrors.aliyun.com/pypi/packages/61/86/cc8d1ff2ca31a312a25a708c891cf9facbad4eae493b3872638db6785eb5/wheel-0.40.0-py3-none-any.whl (64 kB)
           -------------------------------------- 64.5/64.5 kB 862.0 kB/s eta 0:00:00
      Collecting Cython
        Downloading http://mirrors.aliyun.com/pypi/packages/3f/d6/9eed523aeaca42acbaa3e6d3850edae780dc7f8da9df1bf6a2ceb851839c/Cython-0.29.36-py2.py3-none-any.whl (988 kB)
           -------------------------------------- 988.3/988.3 kB 1.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
      Installing collected packages: wheel, setuptools, Cython
      ERROR: Cannot set --home and --prefix together
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

According to the error message, the cause of the error is that the --home and --prefix parameters are set at the same time, but I did not

```
ERROR: Cannot set --home and --prefix together
```

Comment: We've got zero idea what your `development.txt` looks like, so start by having a look there, and if it's still confusing, add that to your question with an edit.

Comment: Could be incorrectly set target in `pip.ini` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/73706040/7976758) or in `PIP_TARGET`; found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+ERROR%3A+Cannot+set+home+and+prefix+together Try `pip config debug` to check.

Comment: development.txt [see https://github.com/apache/superset/blob/master/requirements/development.txt](https://github.com/apache/superset/blob/master/requirements/development.txt)