# pip config issue: can't find pip files from global, user, and site

Tags: python, pip, configuration

I'm trying to install `pip3 install -r requirements.txt` to my project.It failed and showed:

```
......
Using cached itsdangerous-0.24.tar.gz (46 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [5 lines of output]
      Collecting setuptools>=40.8.0
        Using cached setuptools-69.1.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.2 kB)
      Using cached setuptools-69.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (819 kB)
      Installing collected packages: setuptools
      ERROR: Cannot set --home and --prefix together
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
.......
```

I don't know what's going wrong, then I type `pip config debug`, and it showed:

```
env_var:
env:
global:
  C:\ProgramData\pip\pip.ini, exists: False
site:
  C:\Program Files\Python311\pip.ini, exists: False
user:
  C:\Users\Admin\pip\pip.ini, exists: False
  C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\pip\pip.ini, exists: True
    global.target: D:Python
```

If the main problem came from none pip.ini exists? Or there are some conflicts? e.g. I install python on my C drive, while global target on D drive. I would appreciate any help, as I have been trying to fix it for the past two days.

FYI: pip --v 24.0 python --v 3.11.8

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PIP Install ERROR: Cannot set --home and --prefix together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72297487/pip-install-error-cannot-set-home-and-prefix-together)

Comment: It did help me remove the global target after I run `unset global.target`. But it still did work utimately TAT.